# Create a document without returning it, in MongoDB / mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I am creating a lot of documents, and I am concerned that half of the server bandwidth is being spent on returning those new documents back to the caller.

I don't want the server to return the document to me.  I just want to get an acknowledgement once the document has been saved.

I have been able to address this concern when *updating* a document, by using `Model.updateOne()` instead of `Model.findOneAndUpdate()`.

But how can I do the same when creating a document?

So far I have tried:

```
Model.create(docData)

new Model(docData).save()

Model.collection.insert(docData)

Model.collection.insertMany([docData])
```

but in every case, mongoose (or the mongodb driver) returns a document to me.

I am not sure if MongoDB is actually sending the document back over the network, or if it is just sending back the new `_id` and that is being appended to the original data by the driver.  But I fear the former.

How can I save the document without MongoDB sending it back to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mongoose document of insertMany](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) it says that the result is an [insertWriteOpCallback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#~insertWriteOpCallback) which, according to the documentation of mongodb driver says that it return the inserted documents.

---

In other hands the [mongodb documentation about insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) tells us about a [WriteResult object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#WriteResult) that is not returning any document.

---

The answer is that mongodb-driver is adding the inserted document into it's response.

---

What you can do is to use the method [bulkWrite](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) from mongodb-native driver, which allow you to perform an insert and get the mongodb response only (so without documents).

Comment: Thanks. I don't really mind getting a document back from the driver, as long as it hasn't come over the wire. Delving into the docs it seems that, apart from `findOneAndUpdate`, none of these functions do send documents back - it's just an illusion from mongoose or the driver.